# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Slide Tab View

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

Background:

1. Using DLSlideView for Slide Tab view in an iOS Swift App.
2. Project Language selected = Swift
3. Xcode Version = 8.1
4. Bridge Header = created
5. Running platform = Simulator
6. Paths of the import files all set.

Path is set for the bridging header in the Target >> Building Settings >> Swift Compiler - General

I am trying to bridge Objective-C code in a Swift Project. But on compiling I am getting the following error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_DLFixedTabbarView", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in DLTabedSlideView.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_DLFixedTabbarViewTabItem", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in DLTabedSlideView.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_DLLUCache", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in DLTabedSlideView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
cland error: linked commend failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If someone can help as to what is the issue exactly?